# Mono WCF webHttpBinding crashes

Tags: c#, wcf, mono, webhttpbinding

Currently I'm testing a Mono WCF Host, it can receive json post. I find on Mono3.2, if send it a header(via Fiddler) without "Content-Type", something like this, it crashes immediately.

```
User-Agent: Fiddler
Host: myIP:myPort
Content-Length: 1
```

Exception is below.

```
  Missing method Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.SslServerStream::.ctor(Stream,X509Certificate,bool,bool,bool) in assembly G:\share\DaGeneral\Overseer CLI HOST\bin\Debug\Mono.Security.dll, referenced in assembly F:\Mono-3.2.3\lib\mono\gac\System\4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll

Unhandled Exception:
System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.SslServerStream..ctor'.

  at System.Net.EndPointListener.OnAccept (System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e) [0x00099] in C:\cygwin\sources\mono\mcs\class\System\System.Net\EndPointListener.cs:128 

  at System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncEventArgs.OnCompleted (System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncEventArgs e) [0x00014] in C:\cygwin\sources\mono\mcs\class\System\System.Net.Sockets\SocketAsyncEventArgs.cs:177 

  at System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncEventArgs.AcceptCallback (IAsyncResult ares) [0x00077] in C:\cygwin\sources\mono\mcs\class\System\System.Net.Sockets\SocketAsyncEventArgs.cs:290 

  at System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncEventArgs.DispatcherCB (IAsyncResult ares) [0x00084] in C:\cygwin\sources\mono\mcs\class\System\System.Net.Sockets\SocketAsyncEventArgs.cs:230
```

No doubt it could be a huge hidden danger if a programme shut down like this.
Any help? Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is that the file "Mono.Security.Dll" is a wrong compiled version. 
Download a mono version of it can fix this problem.